# Check if XElement is null globally

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a class what takes care of reading and holding the XML file.
Right now a simple version of it looks like this:

```
public class EstEIDPersoConfig
{
    public bool LaunchDebugger { get ; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Slot { get; set; }
    public string Reader { get; set; }
    public string TestInput { get; set; }
    public bool Logging { get; set; }

    public EstEIDPersoConfig()
    {
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(myxml.xml);
        XElement Configuration = xml.Element("Configuration");

        LaunchDebugger = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger").Value);
        Password = Configuration.Element("Password").Value;
        Slot = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.Element("Slot").Value);
        Reader = Configuration.Element("Reader").Value;
        TestInput = Configuration.Element("TestInput").Value;
        Logging = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration.Element("Logging").Value);
     }
 }
```

And there will be more later. so the problem is that if some element does not exist in xml i get `System.NullReferenceException`. So i need to check if the element is `null` or not. Heres one way to do this:

```
var value = Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger").Value;
if (value != null)
    LaunchDebugger = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
else
    throw new Exception("LaunchDebugger element missing from xml!");
```

But doing that for every element would be just too much. So i need some good ideas how to simplify this system so it wouldn't end up in 1000 lines of code.

EDIT: Edited the last code snippet, the idea was not to set a default value, idea was to notify the user that this element whats null is missing from the xml.

Comment: Perform what is called lazy initialization of xml to the appropriate constructor when the value of xml is null.

Comment: @hs2d - I think abatishchev's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here comes directly from abatischev's answer so he deserves the credit.

As perscribed by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx) you can just cast the `XElement` to the type you desire.

```
LaunchDebugger = (bool?)Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger");
```

if you want to handle the `null` case I guess you could do

```
LaunchDebugger = (bool)(Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger") ?? true);
```

or perhaps

```
LaunchDebugger = (bool)(Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger") ?? false);
```

depending on your business logic. If you do the same coalescene for a specific type it may be appropriate to wrap this one liner in a method, extension or otherwise but I'm uncertain it would add much.

Comment: Seems that you need to use `bool?`

Comment: +1 for using the ?? (null coalescing operator, I believe?) to set a default value in the case of null elements.  I've learned two useful things from this thread tonight :)

Comment: except, that this doesn't work for OPs example code: The element might be there, but not have a value...

Comment: If the element is there but doesn't have a value, how would the above not work?  Would that not be equivalent to the element not being there at all?

Answer (score 4):

```
(bool)Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger")
```

or

```
(bool?)Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger")
```

should not throw exception.

See MSDN:

- [XElement Explicit Conversion (XElement to `Boolean`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336181.aspx)
- [XElement Explicit Conversion (XElement to `Nullable<Boolean>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348128.aspx)

Comment: Why the downvote, looks like the best answer to me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell: You seem to be right...my bad. It looks a bit weird though!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(bool?)Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger")`?  I.e., make bool a nullable type.

Comment: +1 as this looks like the most elegant solution.  Simply replace the bool and int properties with bool? and int? and use the cast.

Comment: @Jodrell: Thanks for the link. Downvoters should read MSDN often

Comment: @abatishchev - downvoters should also be required to give a reason for the downvote as well.  It may be either a) an incorrect reason or b) not readily apparent to the person posting the answer.  IMHO.

Comment: Downvoters will downvote. On aggregate, though, abatishchev is ahead of the game ;) +1 from me too!

Answer (score 2):

Extract the logic to a method and have overloaded methods for Int32,boolean and other data types conversion.

```
public static void GetElementValue(XElement xElement, string parameter, out bool value)
    {
        var stringValue = xElement.Element(parameter).Value;
        value = false;
        if (value != null)
            value = Convert.ToBoolean(stringValue);
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an `out` parameter, but the return value. And it would be more useful if the string "LaunchDebugger" was a parameter.

Comment: But this way i still have to create external method for every xml element? Or am i missing something here..

Comment: I can't see that writing a method for every property will help

Comment: @hs2d See the updated  code for that. It should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have an extension method that I use for just this kind of thing:

```
    public static T GetValue<T>(
            this XElement @this,
            XName name, 
            Func<XElement, T> cast, 
            Func<T> @default)
    {
        var e = @this.Element(name);
        return (e != null) ? cast(e) : @default();
    }
```

It gives you the casting required and also a default value factory.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
LaunchDebugger = Configuration.GetValue("LaunchDebugger",
    x => Convert.ToBoolean(x), () => false);
Password = Configuration.GetValue("CMKPassword", x => (string)x, () => "");
Slot = Configuration.GetValue("CMKSlot", x => (int)x, () => -1);
Reader = Configuration.GetValue("Reader", x => (string)x, () => "");
TestInput = Configuration.GetValue("TestInput", x => (string)x, () => "");
Logging = Configuration.GetValue("Logging",
    x => Convert.ToBoolean(x), () => false);
```

Comment: I cant see that passing two lambdas to a generic is better that just casting and using the `??` null coalesence operator

Comment: Why the second lambda instead of a plain value of type "T"?

Comment: @Jodrell - The `cast` lambda is really better thought of as a conversion. I do it that way to make the code consistent.

Comment: @HansKesting - The second lambda is lazily evaluated so if the value is costly to compute then it is only executed when it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about an external method:

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static bool AsBoolean(this XElement self, bool defaultValue)
    {
        if (self == null)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(self.Value))
        {           
            try
            {
                return XmlConvert.ToBoolean(self.Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

I've tested this with SnippetCompiler:

```
XElement test = new XElement("test", 
    new XElement("child1"),
    new XElement("child2", new XText("true")),
    new XElement("child3", new XText("false")),
    new XElement("child4", new XText("rubbish")));

WL(test.Element("child1").AsBoolean(false)); // note, "child1" has no value (or is `""`)
WL(test.Element("child2").AsBoolean(false));
WL(test.Element("child3").AsBoolean(false));
WL(test.Element("child4").AsBoolean(false));
WL(test.Element("child5").AsBoolean(false)); // note, "child5" doesn't exist
```

To produce this result:

```
False
True
False
False
False
```

Add more such methods for other types and also add `AsBoolean(defaultValue)`, as that can come in handy, when you want to default to `true`!

As others have stated, you can use the `??` operator to provide a value for `null`. This doesn't nest, though, so:

```
LaunchDebugger = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(Configuration.Element("LaunchDebugger").Value) ?? false;
```

will through a `NullReferenceException` if there is no such element in the XML file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple to use the microsoft perscribed approach in abatischev's answer with the `??` coalesence operator?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method to extract the value for you and do some checking on null there. So wrap the value retrieval in your own method like so:

```
public string GetXMLValue(XElement config, string elementName){
    var element = Configuration.Element(elementName);

    if(element == null)
        return String.Empty;

    return element.Value;
}
```

Of course you can extend this to work correctly with parsing to boolean etc.

Comment: Why didn't the framework developers add this? Answer, because its not needed. See abatischev's answer.

Comment: @Jodrell: I see that now....I think I actually learned something from this post ;) Thanks man!